# Simulating graphing paper on iPhone

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, quartz-graphics, quartz-2d

I need to implement 'graphing paper' in an iPhone app. The user should be presented with a grid. They user can touch individual squares to turn them on, or if they're already on, off.The user can pinch to zoom  and scroll around the paper as well..

So far I'm thinking Quartz 2D + UIScrollView is the way to do this but these are both areas of iPhone development that I'm unfamiliar with. Does this seem like a reasonable strategy?

Comment: In the end, I implemented this with a UIWebView, HTML and Javascript!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this would be the way to go. You could also create a UIView and give it a background color based off an image (+[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:]), but, myself, I'd go with option (a).